# SNMP4J send never times out

Tags: java, timeout, snmp, snmp4j

I'm having a problem while using the SNMP4J library.  My code works great when the SNMP server I'm sending the request to is running, but when it isn't running, I want the SNMP request to eventually time-out.  However, it never times out.  For example, the code below, even when dcadb2 does not exist (i.e. can not ping this host name), the program will never print "Timed out".  It will attempt to reach the device for infinity.

```
private ResponseEvent getSnmpResponse() {
    PDU pdu = createPdu();
    Target target = getTarget();
    try {
        ResponseEvent event = snmp.send(pdu, target, null);
        return event;
    }
    catch (IOException e ){
        System.out.println("Timed out");  
    }
}

protected PDU createPdu() {
    PDU pdu = new PDU();
    pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(DISK_TOTAL_OID)));
    pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(DISK_AVAIL_OID)));
    pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(DISK_USED_OID)));
    pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(DISK_PERCENT_USED_OID)));
    pdu.setType( PDU.GET );
    return pdu;
}

private Target getTarget() {
    CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();
    target.setCommunity( new OctetString("public") );
    target.setAddress( GenericAddress.parse("dcadb2/161") );
    target.setRetries( 1 );
    target.setTimeout( 1000L );
    target.setVersion( SnmpConstants.version2c );
    return target;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It turns out SNMP4J (or at least the version I'm using, 1.11.2) will time out if you give it an IP that doesn't exist, but not if you give it a hostname that doesn't exist.  In the latter case, the thread will continue for infinity.  So the solution is to use IP addresses.

Comment: A rather old version, isn't it?